# From fragmentA open FragmentB + method

Tags: android

I need to open FragmentB + FragmentsB method, using FragmentA

To be more precise, what I have and what I neeed:

1. EmptyProfile.class with button openProfile().
2. ArtistProfileView.class with method openProfileDialog()

So, When user is on EmptyProfile.class he presses a button openProfile, which will call:

ArtistProfileView.class + automatically openProfileDialog() to be opened.

What, I have tried. I tried to open ArtistProfileView.class with replacing fragments.It works fine, but, in this case, I will simply open ArtistProfileView.class, and then user should click by himself openProfileDialog.

```
  btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
  ArtistProfileView myFragment = new ArtistProfileView();
  activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
  .replace(((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId(), myFragment)
  .commit();
 }
});
```

This part of code is using, to open profileDialog(); at ArtistProfileView.class

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.ivEditPersonal
my_tag = 1
dialogPersonalProfile();
 break;
```

So, I assume that, when I'm on EmptyProfile.class I must call something like

myFragment.my_tag = 1
dialogPersonalProfile();
Or I did something wrong in general?
Thank you!

When user is on EmptyProfile.class, he can press button Fill the Profile, and automatically ArtistProfileView is opened + automatically dialogPersonalProfile is opened as well.

Comment: Why don't you give a button on that fragment in which you want the user to click a button to open that dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put information about the fact that you need to open dialog in a bundle:

```
FragmentsB fragment = new FragmentsB();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putBool("START_DIALOG", true);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then in your FragmentsB retrieve the data (e.g. in onCreate() method) with:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
       if (bundle.getBool("START_DIALOG", false){
            showDialogMethod();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the case is like always you want to show Dialog in ArtisProfileView as fragments gets called from anywhere.
Try calling dialogPersonalProfile() function in onResume method of ArtistProfileView. Also do not forget to dismiss dialog in onPause.

otherwise send bundle with some boolean flag and use it.